# grep command returning 0 - match all characters that are not digits globally

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I am looking to search a file for all strings that do not contain digits, I've come up with the following regex.

```
\D*/g
```

Which works as I want in the this online tool: https://regex101.com/#pcre, but when I run the following command:

```
grep -c "\D*/g" nonDistortResults.txt
```

It is returning `0`.

The file is formatted as follows:

```
2573
kitchenDoor 2573
2573
2573
2573
2574
2574
2574
2574
kitchenDoor 2574
2574
2574
2575
2575
2575
2575
2575
kitchenDoor 2575
2576
```

So in the above example I would expect it to return `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt your pattern as follow:

```
grep -c \D nonDistortResults.txt
```

- We do not need the 'greedy' flag as grep already works with lines
- The quotes are not required here
- The star can be any number of results, including 0 (so using it will return true for every line)

If you need to use again some Pearl regular expressions (PCRE), you can have a look at the -P option of grep but the manual page says:

> -P, --perl-regexp
>   Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.